# value="<%request.getParameter%>" doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm sorry for my english.
I have a parameter in my `jsp` named action I get it and put it in an another parameter named also action because i need it in my servlet

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="<%request.getParameter("action"); %>" />
<input type="submit" value="Suivre" />
```

So when I print this: `<%out.println(request.getParameter("action")); %>`. i got the value, but in the servlet the result is like this: String action ="";

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
```

where is the problem?? thanks

**Edit:** as @arjuncc and @Neuron says i change it to `value=<%=request.getParameter("action")%>`, it works but I have an / added in the end of String action, I will use subString for that and it WORKS, Thanks every body, specially @arjuncc and @Neuron

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use **<%=request.getParameter("action")%>** instead of 
**<%request.getParameter("action")%>**.

Answer (score 2):

I Strongly suggest you to use [Expression Language](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm) , There are many problems with using scriptlets [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

- Reusability: you can't reuse scriptlets.
- Replaceability: you can't make scriptlets abstract.
- OO-ability: you can't make use of inheritance/composition.
- Debuggability: if scriptlet throws an exception halfway, all you get is a blank page.
- Testability: scriptlets are not unit-testable.
- Maintainability: per saldo more time is needed to maintain mingled/cluttered/duplicated code logic.

The problem with your code is that, you have used the [scriplet](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-scriptlet-tag) 
 `<% %>` in your code, which suppose to provide the ability to insert java code inside the jsp. In order to print something in your page you have to use the [JSP expression tag](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-expression-tag) `<%= %>`

```
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='<%=request.getParameter("action") %>' />
<input type="submit" value="Suivre" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In general scriplets should be avoided. Use JSP EL:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="${action}" />
```

Comment: I'm learning JSP so tell now I still do know nothing about EL

Comment: I mean I'm a beginner, I know that they are JSP but I still didn't got that far

Comment: The beginning is the best time to learn best practices.  Why don't you try making a GitHub Gist that contains the pertinent files you are using such as web.xml, .jsp files and any servlets.  This will help others answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In first look

change the below

```
"<%request.getParameter("action"); %>"
```

to (without quote)

```
<%request.getParameter("action"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSP expression `<%= .... %>` note `=` after % *(Not recommended way)*

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="<%=request.getParameter("action"); %>" />
```

---

**Do not write scriptlets in JSP**, because scriptlets shouldn't be used in JSPs for more than a decade. Learn the JSP [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and use servlet for the Java code. [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="{param.action}" />
```